# react native update flatlist when new data is added to database

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

can you help me please i am struggling from this problem
 is there any way to update flatlist when new data is added to data base 
i am using redux

Can anyone help?
from the componentDidMount i call the function from the redux action so i get the data this is the first render

this my code with redux action and reducer
code sample

````
  componentDidMount() {this.props.Orders()}

  render() {

    {
      this.props.data != null ? <FlatList
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        data={this.props.data.orders}
        renderItem={this._renderListItem}
        initialNumToRender={50}
        keyExtractor={item => (item.order.id).toString()}
      /> : null
    }


    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    error: state.orders.error,
    loading: state.orders.loading,
    data: state.orders.data
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { Orders })(Pending);```


i try to use 
 extraData={this.props.data.orders}
 extraData={this.props}
 extraData={this.state}

nothing is working 

//action where i call the api

export const Orders = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: ORDERS_ATTEMPT });

        axios({
            url: '**',
            method: 'POST',
            //data: data,
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

            }
        })
            .then(resp => handleResponse(dispatch, resp.data))
            .catch(error => console.error(error));

    };
}

// rducer

import {
    ORDERS_ATTEMPT,
    ORDERS_SUCCESS,
    ORDERS_FAILED
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { data: null, loading: false, error: '', }

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ORDERS_ATTEMPT:
            return { ...INITIAL_STATE, loading: true }
        case ORDERS_FAILED:
            return { ...INITIAL_STATE, loading: false, error: action.error }
        case ORDERS_SUCCESS:
            return { ...INITIAL_STATE, loading: false, data: action.data }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
````

Comment: When you props update, it will auto update the view. Could you show where you update your data? Remember that, you have to return new array everytime you update your data.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` is only called once, thus the props are not being updated.

So, you need to update the props in the `componentDidUpdate`.
Try something like this:-

try this as below :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(!equal(this.props, prevProps))
In your flatlist put 
  {

    this.props.Orders();
  }
}
```

Check this link out :-
[componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: i try to use your solution 
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

    if (this.props.data !== prevProps.data) {
      this.props.Orders();
    }
  }

but the flaltlis keep refreshing i don't know why every time i call the function the data return to null and then componentDidUpdate keep working and keep fetching data

Comment: do you need to compulsarily go with flatlist, as you can achieve the same with `ScrollView` as well

Comment: if you want an example, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try to add pull to refresh functionality to your Flatlist. [Check this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#onrefresh)

```
<FlatList
    data={this.props.data.orders}
    renderItem={this._renderListItem}
    initialNumToRender={50}
    keyExtractor={item => (item.order.id).toString()}
    refreshing={this.props.loading}
    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
/>
```

Inside handleRefresh function call your this.props.Orders() to fetch data.

```
handleRefresh = () => {
    this.props.Orders()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When data updated send a parameter in flatlist and set in extraData.
Example like this:

```
<FlatList
                {...this.props}
                data={itemList}
                extraData={update}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
                   <View></View>
                }
            />
```

I think this will help you.